# vba functions malfunction after repetitive calling

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database where data goes through multiple steps, and user can report and 'solve' those errors in the database.

Once an error is added in my `tbl_errors`, they go on and solve it. Once they have solved the error irl, the 'solve' the error in the database as well, to keep track of time and such.

This all works like a charm, when adding errors I have never encountered any problems. And at first sight, 'solving' the problems goes flawless either. The problem however, is that once I start 'solving' a lot of errors in a row, my code suddenly stops working.

It does not freeze or throw back any errors, and when I step through the code using my breakpoints and f8, all the variables seem to be correct also. Everything goes on just as always, except it just does not do anything anymore. This is only applicable to that specific error. When I add new errors, and try to 'solve' them. It works just as usual.

**Important notes:**

- This ONLY happens when I start fast clicking on my solve button, thus calling the functions real fast behind eachother.
- It only freezes for a specific errors. (Can be multiple) All other errors can be solved as usual, indicating that the code is still functioning.
- I have stepped through the whole code, while checking all the keys and variables and every variable is correct.
- Even though my code goes through the recordset, it does not update anything?

Below is a piece of my relationships screen to give a better understanding of the table structure, as well as the specific parts of code.

[image]

Calling the code in the OnClick event:

```
Private Sub solve_Click()
    SolveError getorderid(gvStepDelivery), get_errorID(gvCategory, get_stepsID(gvStepNr))
    Me.qry_errors_subform.Requery
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

The self-written function SolveError:

```
Public Function SolveError(Current_order_ID As Long, Category_ID As Long)
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_errors", dbOpenDynaset)
With rs
    .FindFirst "[Error_ID] = " & DLookup("Error_ID", "tbl_errors", "[Current_orders_ID] = " & Current_order_ID & " AND [Category_ID] = " & Category_ID)
    .Edit
        ![Solved_By] = get_user
        ![Solved_Date] = Date
        ![Solved_Time] = Time
    .update
End With
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

There are other parts of code involved (See the SolveError's parameters), but I don't think they will add some usefull info, since they are just returning the correct values. (They are correct!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I have already found my answer. Since I was probably calling a new iteration before the previous one had completely finished, it simply stopped working. Adding the `DoEvents` function at the end my `SolveErrors` function solved it. I have yet to experience the problem again.

```
Public Function SolveError(Current_order_ID As Long, Category_ID As Long)
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_errors", dbOpenDynaset)
With rs
    .FindFirst "[Error_ID] = " & DLookup("Error_ID", "tbl_errors", "[Current_orders_ID] = " & Current_order_ID & " AND [Category_ID] = " & Category_ID)
    .Edit
        ![Solved_By] = get_user
        ![Solved_Date] = Date
        ![Solved_Time] = Time
    .update
End With
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
    DoEvents   'This one did the trick!!
End Function
```

Info on the DoEvents method can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

and here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/doevents-function-HA001228827.aspx